# Listar imágenes dentro de un directorio y separar por extensión

Tags: php, regex, archivo

Busco la manera de hacer funcionar este código:

```
<?php
    $directory="/img";
    $dirint = dir($directory);
    while (($archivo = $dirint->read()) !== false)
    {
        if (eregi("gif", $archivo) || eregi("jpg", $archivo) || eregi("png", $archivo)){
            echo '<img src="'.$directory."/".$archivo.'">'."\n";
        }
    }
    $dirint->close();
?>
```

Como sabrán el `eregi();` ya no funciona en php y quisiera encontrar un remplazo para ejecutar la misma función  de listar las imagenes dentro del directorio y separarlas por extensión. Ejemplo `.jpg`, `.png`, y `.gif`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal cual dice en el [manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/function.eregi.php)

> Las alternativas a esta función son:
>
> - [preg_match()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.preg-match.php) (con el modificador *i* (**PCRE_CASELESS**))

O sea, para comparar si un string termina con alguna de esas extensiones:

```
if (preg_match( '/\.(?:jpe?g|png|gif)$/i', $archivo)) {
    echo "El archivo $archivo tiene una extensión de imagen.<br>\n";
}
```

Pero no hace falta usar una expresión regular. Se puede obtener fácilmente con [**glob()**](http://php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php) con la opción **GLOB_BRACE**.

```
$directory='/img/';
foreach (glob($directory . '*.{jpg,jpeg,png,gif}', GLOB_BRACE) as $archivo) {
    echo "El archivo $archivo tiene una extensión de tipo imagen.<br>\n";
}
```

Sólo tiene una contra, que **no ignora mayúsculas/minúsculas**, por lo que si todas las extensiones no están en minúsculas se puede adaptar a algo como:

```
$directory='/img/';
foreach (glob($directory . '*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG,gif,GIF}', GLOB_BRACE) as $archivo) {
    echo "El archivo $archivo tiene una extensión de tipo imagen.<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta es justo lo que buscaba

Comment: Hola no se por que no lista la imagenes dentro del directorio puedes darme alguna respuesta

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions la primera solución, con `preg_match()` sólo compara strings, para recorrer el directorio como lo estabas haciendo.

Comment: usando **glob()** no muestra nada  y usando  **preg_match()**  muestra el nombre de la imagen pero no las separa por extencion

Comment: como seria la manera correcta de usar **foreach (glob("*.{jpg,JPG,jpeg,JPEG,png,PNG,gif,GIF}", GLOB_BRACE) as $archivo) {
    echo "El archivo $archivo tiene una extensión de tipo imagen.\n";
}** para leer el contenido de la carpeta

Comment: @BotXtremSolutions con `glob()` probablemente sea sólo un tema del directorio. Recién edité la respuesta para agregarlo, y subí una demo con 2 archivos en el directorio en http://mariano.uphero.com/118989/ ..... Con `preg_match()` identifica cuál tiene alguna de esas 4 extensiones con el `if`. Si quisieras separar cuál es `jpg`, cuál `png`, etc. es sencillo, pero no estaba ni en tu código original ni en tu pregunta.

Comment: gracias ya funciona bien

Comment: @Mariano aún tendrás el código funcionando? estoy intentando pero no lo he logrado